# Variable undefined when creating html in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html file where a new instance of javascript `gmap` object is assigned to the variable `gMap`in `$(document).ready`

Now I call a function of the `gmap`object in `onClick` attribute with `gMap.function_a()` and it works perfectly.

Now my problem: In the js file where the `gmap` object is defined, I create html too and want to assign an `onClick` attribute that calls a function.
But there gMap is undefined. How can I access it from there?

**HTML file:**

```
<script>
    var gMap;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        gMap  = new gmap({
            ...
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a onclick="gMap.function_a(gMap.myMap)></a>  //works
```

**JavaScript file:**

```
var gmap = (function () {
var myMap;
...}
gmap.prototype = {
    //here is a function where a google map is created and assigned to myMap
    function_b: function() {
        var link = '<a onClick="gMap.myMap.setZoom(18);">...</a>';  //Cannot read property 'setCenter' of undefined
        $(#container).append(link);
    }
```

I also tried to call `myMap.setZoom` instead of `gMap.myMap.setZoom` but it didn't work either.

Comment: Side note: Don't name two different variables `gMap` and `gmap`, you're probably going to confuse the two of them.

Comment: When are you seeing the "gMap is undefined" error?  When you click on the link?

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat Yes

Comment: `gMap.myMap` (or `gmap.prototype.myMap`) is never defined, also script in attributes are executed in the global scope and `myMap` does not exist in the global scope.

Comment: function_b - function_a?

Comment: @Musa But why can I call `gMap.function(gMap.myMap)` in html file with `gMap.myMap` as parameter?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like in your HTML code:

```
<script>
    var gMap;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        gMap  = new gmap({
            ...
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a onclick="gMap.function_a(gMap.myMap)></a>  //works
```

`onClick` executes `.function_a()` of a valid instance of `new gmap` with `"undefined"` as a parameter, so if the function exists it "works", it does something.

In your second example you are trying to run `.myMap.setZoom()` as a property of `"undefined"` and its throwing an error because undefined can't have properties.

I'd recommend you to put all the code you wrote in your html example inside your .js file, add the `<a>` tag from there with the correct values  and require it from your html using `<script src="">`.